# Validate XML against XSD without callback

Tags: .net, xml, powershell, xsd, xml-validation

I am looking for an as-simple-as-possible .NET way to validate an XML file against an XSD file, like so:

```
validator.IsValid(xmlFile, xsdFile)
```

I've found a few questions (and answers) on stackoverflow but they all require a callback function. I am aiming for a oneliner since I'd like to execute this in a PowerShell:

```
$validator = new-object SomeValidator
$validator.IsValid(xmlFile, xsdFile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) and use the `Test-Xml` cmdlet. This cmdlet not only tests for well formedness, it can also validate against a schema. Be sure to grab the 2.1 (or 3.0) beta as the 2.0 production version has a bug with schema validation.  Here's an example:

```
Test-Xml $xmlfile -Schema $xsdFile
```